# What is difference between Shift and ShiftTemplate in employee rostering. What is the purpose of these two becasue these are almost same

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I was reading code in GitHub and i was not able to understand the difference between Shift.java and ShiftTemplate.java class. These classes contain almost the same fields then what is the purpose behind creating these two classes.

Answer (score 0):

- Shift has a date.
- ShiftTemplate has an offset, but no date.

In the image below, Shifts are the rectangles in the first 2 bands. ShiftTemplate are the rectangles in the 3th band.

[image]

Comment: Okay I understand, But still I am not able to understand why we need shift template here. Can you please explain me briefly that why we need this is class?

Comment: "The first two bands" vs "the third band" -- what exactly are you referring to?  By "band" do you mean "row"?  Also, by "rectangle", are you referring to the smallest rectangles in the drawings?  I also need clarification on the purpose of the shift template.